# Extracting point data from EPSG 4326 image

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, point-of-interest

I am new in the field.

I am trying to extract remote sensing data from selected points. I am using a remote sensing image with CRS of EPSG:4326. I defined the points which I will extract data from by entering their longitude and latitude as decimal degrees. (I was given this information both in decimal degrees and in degrees - minutes - seconds. I checked them using Google Maps to see if they correspond to my locations of interest.) I am using QGIS for extracting the point data from remote sensing image.

The question I have is; since the EPSG 4326 is not a projection, would the point data I get from the image be accurate this way? Or should I project the image first before extracting the data?

I am only interested in the remote sensing data I will extract from the point locations.

Comment: Are you using any particular software for this?

Comment: I have tried using both QGIS and Google Earth Engine.

Answer (score 1):

EPSG 4326 is a coordinate system. Its units are degrees of latitude and longitude. If you define the lat/long of a point, then you know where that point is. **There's nothing wrong with using EPSG 4326 for locating points**.

You'll have accuracy problems if you try to calculate distance, area or angles in EPSG 4326, but that's not what you're doing. If you want to make those calculations you can always reproject your points later.

Comment: I would like to clarify one more thing if possible, I defined the latitude and longitude by entering the decimal degrees. Is it incorrect?

Comment: It seems like that should be a separate question, but you'll need to explain exactly what steps you took if you want advice that's specific to your situation. As it is, I can't figure out what you're talking about. Where did you define lat/long? Where did you get the lat/long information if you didn't get it from your GIS software? Which GIS software did you do this in? Please don't answer in comments, just write a new question with enough information to understand what steps you took and what you're trying to achieve.